# What commit styles are available in MongoDB?

Tags: insert, mongodb, save, commit, upsert

In some sense, the default "save" operation appears to be asynchronous in MongoDB.  It seems that when a client saves a document, it will typically receive a successful response immediately from the server, even if the operation has not yet been applied to the database (let alone committed to disk).

(I'm basing this model for how `save()` behaves on the PHP client [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.save.php), which contains an optional parameter--`safe`--which I think *does* ensure that the save has been processed by the server, rather than merely received by the server, and a [blog post comment](http://www.mikealrogers.com/2010/07/mongodb-performance-durability/comment-page-1/#comment-1730) by Mathias Stearn in which he says "By default 'commited' just means applied to the mmaped structure, but it can also mean replicated or flushed to disk.")

I can see that there are several levels of "success" a `save()` might reach, including: (a) sent by client; (b) received by server; (c) committed by server to internal datastructures; (d) sent by server to n replicas; and (e) committed to disk.

- What does MongoDB do by default?
- How can this be tuned?  (I couldn't find an equivalent for PHP's `safe` mode in the mongo shell, for example.)

Also, is there ever any difference in behaviour toward the client issuing the `save()`, and any other client?  i.e. does MongoDB support read-your-own-writes, or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these options are done w/ the getLastError command. That is basically what "safe mode" does under the hood. This page should be helpful:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command

Comment: Somewhat counter-intuitive, but it appears that yes, without any options, getLastError blocks and waits for the previously issued command to be committed to memory.  A [comment on the "Last Error Commands" page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Last+Error+Commands#comment-61398549) explains how to trigger various commit styles by passing different options to getLastError().

Comment: actually - *any read operation* will block and wait for previously issued writes (on the same connection) to be committed to memory. a getLastError w/ no options achieves the same by virtue of being a read.

Comment: @mdirolf can you reference some documentation that states that? This page (http://blog.mongodb.org/post/498145601/on-distributed-consistency-part-2-some-eventual) seems to imply that it is possible with Mongo to get stale data in a read (though I recognize you left this answer a long time ago).